# Converting $\LaTeX$ expression in Mathematica -- strange result

Tags: latex, conversion

I tried to convert a $\LaTeX$ expression in Mathematica, but it shows me a strange result (it shows a strange word: "ghit").

```
ToExpression["\\frac{s + k_{12} + k_{02}}
 {V_1 \left[ s^2 + s \left(  k_{12} + k_{02} + k_{21} + k_{01} \r\
ight)  + \left(  k_{21} \, k_{02} + k_{01} \, k_{12} + k_{01} \, \
k_{02} \right) \right] }", TeXForm]
```

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't the single ``\ `` be a double ``\\ ``? (You can evaluate the string by itself [to see the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2JUpJ.png).)

Comment: You have to use a backslash ``\`` as escape character for ``\`` (and also for `"`) when you manipulate strings in Mathematica, exactly as you did in `"\\frac{...}"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslashes, i.e. `\`, *must* be escaped in Mathematica strings.

This is incorrect syntax:

```
"\xyz"
```

The correct syntax is

```
"\\xyz"
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica tries to be "user-friendly" and when using the notebook interface, it accepts `"\xyz"` without complaint.  (If using the terminal, it at least shows a warning.)  This creates the false impression that it's fine to do this. It's not. Sequences like `\r` (which you used), `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, etc. have special meanings.  New escape sequences may also be added in the future, breaking code like `"\xyz"`.

Thus: *always, always escape backslashes in strings!*.

```
str = "\\frac{s + k_{12} + k_{02}}{V_1 \\left[ s^2 + s \\left(  k_{12} + k_{02} + k_{21} + k_{01} \\right)  + \\left(  k_{21} \\, k_{02} + k_{01} \\, k_{12} + k_{01} \\, k_{02} \\right) \\right] }";

ToExpression[str, TeXForm]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your excellent solution and explanation!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent MMA from dropping the zero in $k_{02}$?

Comment: @Casimir Good point. I did not notice that. I do not know how to do what you are asking. It is not even about dropping it, but getting it to understand that $0$ and $2$ are two separate numbers.  This is a good example of notation that is clear to a human, but not at all to a computer.  `k_{0,2}` would produce a better result.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Be aware of the problem pointed out by Casimir above.

Comment: I think it drops the zero from `02` since evaluator replaces it by `2` right away. Same thing when doing `Subscript[x,02]` which gives $x_2$. and not $x_{02}$

Comment: @Casimir You could use `k_{\"02\"}` instead of `k_{02}`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes ofcourse, but normally these Latex expressions are taken from some Latex source code as is. This means one would first need a pre-processing phase to do this, i.e. before feeding it to Mathematicas`ToExpression[str, TeXForm]`. Having to do this manually each time and for each such occurrence, would be pain I would think.